# Are Domain Models different from the Database models?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

I understand the concepts in DDD but in practise it gets a bit confusing.

I am using C#, SQL Server and EF. I see that based on my database schema, the persistence models would look different from my aggregates. In order to define clean, nice aggregates, entities and value objects, my domain models would look different from the database models.

Moreover, if I try to merge these 2 then somehow I try to design my domain models more based on technology, not on domain.

Maybe a more concrete example would be for example:

- Do I need to add an ID field in the entity if that id is used just for DB?
- In case of Many2Many relationships it can also get tricky

Are these 2 models different and the implementation of the repository must convert db model into domain model or I should make the domain models the same as the models used by EF?

Comment: This is probably a better fit for software engineering. Its a little broad and those kids dont mind splattering off pages of subjective SE topic banter

Comment: https://blog.sapiensworks.com/post/2012/04/07/Just-Stop-It!-The-Domain-Model-Is-Not-The-Persistence-Model.aspx

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's a common issue when you start with DDD.

They are *completely* separate things.

A *Domain Model* is an abstraction. It should not concern itself about the technology that you are using and it doesn't represent database tables, documents, classes, functions etc.

The *Domain Model* represents concepts, dependencies and interactions between these concepts.

Technology is used for the **Implementation** of a **Domain Model**.

Different technologies can be used to implement the same **Domain Model**.

As much as we would like to have the freedom do do whatever we like with your domain models, in practice we do use a technology for it's implementation and sometimes this will affect it.

Of course you can dump all frameworks and libraries and make your own solutions that will make your implementation a lot easier. Even if you do this you are still left with your language, C#, Java, Ruby etc... and the tools that it provides you.

Here's an example:

Let's say we develop a system for car rentals. A person can rent a car. In our *Domain* we have the concept of an *Account* that a *Person* has, a `Car` and a `CarRental`.

That's your *Domain Model*. At this point we are not concerned with the language, database or anything

Now to the *Implementation* of the *Domain Model*.

We will use C#. Now we need to decide for a database. If we decide to use SQL, we may decide to use the nice abilities of RDBMS to do joins so we may implement it by using integer IDs this way:

```
public class Account {
    public int ID { get; private set; }
    // other stuff
}

public class Car {
    public int ID { get; private set; }
    // other stuff
}

public class CarRental {
    public int AccountID { get; private set; }
    public int CarID { get; private set; }
    // other stuff
}
```

On the other hand we may decide that integer ID's are not good because you can get collisions if you have to work with other systems and move databases and stuff, so we decide to think a bit and use an e-mail as a unique identifier for the Account and the license place as a unique identifier for the Car:

```
public class Account {
    public Email Email { get; private set; }
    // other stuff
}

public class Car {
    public LicensePlace LicensePlace { get; private set; }
    // other stuff
}

public class CarRental {
    public Email AccountEmail { get; private set; }
    public LicensePlace CarLicensePlace { get; private set; }
    // other stuff
}
```

If we follow DDD and divide your *Entities* into *Aggregates* properly, you should not need to do joins between them as they should not be loaded or changes in the same transaction.

On the other hand, we may want to build a different model (read model maybe if we use CQRS, or we may need to extract reports) on top of the same database and using the second approach can make this harder since we loose the ability to do joins.

On the other hand, if we use a NoSQL database like MongoDB for example, we don't have the ability to do joins. So using integer ID's doesn't bring us any value.

Even if we decide use a SQL database and don't use integer ID's we can still use *Domain Events* and build additional models and reporting using them.

Also using joins won't work if we have a distributed system, so using integer ID's may not bring us any value at all.

Sometimes it's convenient to use the abilities of your technology to make some things easier, but we let it harm our *Systems* and *Domain Models*.

We end up building system that are very robust from technological point of view but they don't do the things that they are supposed to do, and that makes them useless.

A **useless** system is **useless** no matter how good it's implemented.

If you haven't read the [DDD](https://books.google.bg/books/about/Domain_Driven_Design.html?id=hHBf4YxMnWMC&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) book, read it. Eric Evans talks about how you technology can either help you or fight you all the way. Eric Evans also talks about how DDD allows for a freedom of implementation so that you don't have to fight your technology.

Another thing that we tend to do if think all the time about persistence. It's true that we persist things most of the time but that doesn't mean that a *Domain Model* is something that is *Persisted* to a database.

When I started programming, I started with computer graphics and modeling applications like 3DsMax and Maya. When I started to write applications that use the holly **Database** it was really weird to me how people don't think and don't know about their domains, just persist stuff and make them work and all they talk about is technology.

If you are into computer graphics you won't be able to write a single like of code if you don't know ***Math***. So you start with learning ***Math***. After you know some of it, then you can write code.

Let's take games for example. You may design a **Physics Engine** that models the *Domain of physics* . In this model you will have concepts like **Work**, **Power**, **Gravity**, **Acceleration** etc. It's not necessary to persist them. You do persist other concepts like **Weight** of your **Player** for example so that the **Physics Engine** will know how gravity should affect it, but still you don't persist **Power** to the database. It's still a **Domain Model**. **Power**, **Work** etc are functions, not entities of aggregates. They are still part of your *Domain Model*.

Let's say you want to build a **Physics engine** The thing is that ***if you want to build a Physics Engine you have to know Physics***. Physics is complex. Even if you are a really good programming knowing in EF or SQL of whatever, it won't help you build **Physics engines**. Knowing the **Domain of physics** and being able to make a ***Domain Model*** of it and then ***Implement it*** is the key.

If you want to really feel the difference between a Domain model from Implementation, check [this out](http://www.pbr-book.org/3ed-2018/contents.html), This domain can blow your mind before you get to any implementation.

Also check [this article](https://kalele.io/modeling-aggregates-with-ddd-and-entity-framework/) on modeling entities with DDD.

**EDIT**

[Here is another](https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2018/06/13/ef-core-vs-nhibernate-ddd-perspective/)  article that explains differences between NHibernate and EntityFramework for Domain Modeling.

Comment: Hi @expandable, Thank you very much for this explanation. I mainly got the idea.
I think this last article is exactly what I was looking for. I will read it fully.
So what I got to answer my question is that the domain Model implementation can also be used for DBContext in EF. Is that right?

Comment: ORM classes are typically a lot less restrictive than domain classes.  What one typically finds is that when going down the road of using a domain model as your ORM model, or vice versa, is that the domain model ends up rather anemic.  ORMs like access to all data and encapsulation goes out the window leaving more of a DTO than a domain class.  I try to avoid ORMs when doing domain driven design but I have had to use EF in the past and then I map between the EF object (entity) and my domain objects in the repository.

Comment: Aha. It makes sense now. I spent some time looking at some other examples and as you say, preferably you have them separate to keep it clean. But it does not mean that if the model is simple, you cannot use it also as the entity for EF.

The problem that I have with having entity for EF and a separate class for domain model is that now, as you say, you need to map these 2 somewhere. We pay a lot for having these separated. Maintaining another layer and mappers is not that nice I would say.

Comment: Yes, you can use EF classes as entities and aggregates. ORMs are becoming more suited to be used with nice domain models.Unfortunately, sometimes more complex things are harder do to, but if your model allows it you can use EF directly without having another layer. In one of the applications that I'm working we couldn't make EF behave the way we wanted, so we had to have two classes, EF entities and out Domain Model classes and we had our Repositories map between them. We paid the price but it was worth it as using EF directly was a nightmare. In other cases it works fine.