# Can we use Entity Framework for working objects saving?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In many Entity Framework examples, objects stored in the database are represented as:

```cs
public class Animal {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int Age {get; set;}

    //...
}
```

If I want to use the Enity Framework not just for classes with a set of properties / fields and some small methods, but also write the fields of large full-fledged objects through it to the database, with which the program will work, for example:

```cs
public class Animal : BaseObject {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int Age {get; set;}

    //...

    public void voice() { /*...*/ }
    public void func1() { /*...*/ }
    public int func2() { /*...*/ }

   //И т.д.
}
```

Is the Entity Framework designed to work with classes with complex logic and inheritance from others, or should you make classes that are purely for working with the database?
For example:

Database class

```cs
public class DBAnimal {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int Age {get; set;}

    //И т.д...
}
```

Working class

```cs
public class Animal : BaseObject {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int Age {get; set;}

    //И т.д...
    
    public Animal(DBAnimal dbAnimal) {
        this.Id = dbAnimal.Id;
        this.Name = dbAnimal.Name;
        this.Age = dbAnimal.Age;
    }    

    public void voice() { /*...*/ }
    public void func1() { /*...*/ }
    public int func2() { /*...*/ }

   //И т.д.
}
```

There is also a second question:
If you still use the Entity framework to work with full-fledged classes, is there some kind of annotation that would make all the fields of the NotMapped class by default, and the annotation of the Mapped type would be applied to the required fields?

Comment: You can have a property that contains the entity such as `public DBAnimal DbAnimal { get; set; }`

Comment: You could do it, but in the long run you should consider not doing it. Having a separate set of classes for the data model allows you separating the functions, so changes in the data model would not break existing working and tested functions and viceversa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entity framework does [support inheritance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance), so you probably can do things like this. A better question to ask is should you?

A principle of domain driven design (DDD) argue that the storage model should be separated from the domain model. See [Are Domain Models different from the Database models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56615438/are-domain-models-different-from-the-database-models).

The primary argument is that the model that fits for storage may not be appropriate for working with the model and vice versa. For example, you might discover that to get the required performance you need some optimized search structure that the database cannot accommodate.

Another common problem is that the model might change, but you will still need to handle old data. Having a storage model provides a convenient place for conversion code if that is needed. You might even have multiple storage models. Having a simple file-based storage is very convenient for things like testing for example.